# Show different buttons based on current value in database PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I'm currently building a basic Clock in / Clock out system.

I've got the vast majority of it working, but I just need some guidance.

The user is initially displayed a page (index.php) where they have to select their name from a dropdown list (populated from a database) and click 'Login'. When they click 'Login', the name they selected is posted to the next page (clock.php) which displays their name and asks them to Clock in or to Clock Out via 2 buttons.

The 2 buttons (Clock In and Clock Out), I would like to hide one of them based on the current value stored in the 'clockAction' column in my MySQL database (either "In" or "Out").

When the user clicks one of the buttons an entry is added to the database with a unique ID, their name and which button they pressed. The database also adds a timestamp in its own column.

I basically need a query which queries the table to find out if the 'Logged in' user is 'Clocked in' (Specified by ClockAction value being "In") and if so, only displays the 'Clock Out' button on the page. And vice versa. But this must be the most recent entry for them.

I currently have this SQL query:

```
SELECT id, user, time 
FROM clock 
WHERE user = '" . $user ."' 
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Which works when input directly on PHPmyAdmin (obviously I have to manually specify $user). But I'm not sure how to structure that into and if/else statement.

It sounds confusing but its quite a basic premise, I just cant work out how I would achieve this.

Thanks in advance, and if anyone needs any clarification I'm happy to do so.

*Jack :)*

Comment: `WHERE user = blah and loggedin=logged_in and clockin=clockedin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your `clockAction` field to your query.

```
SELECT id, user, time, clockAction
FROM clock 
WHERE user = '" . $user ."' 
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

and compare the content of this field (assume you've read the result of your query to an assoziative array `$result`)

```
if ($result['clockAction'] == 'In') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do the opposite
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! No I have not read the results to an array, how would I go about doing this? Thank you

Comment: since I don't know anything about your application and how you access the database I can`t tell you. Have a look at the PHP Dokumentation for an example e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php if you use PDO

Comment: maybe you can give a bit code how you read data from database

Comment: I use `$link = mysqli_connect("IP.ADD.RE.SS", "username", "password", "database");` to connect to the database and `$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT clockAction FROM clock WHERE user = '" . $user."' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1");` to get the data.

Comment: so you just need to ```$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);``` after ```$sql = mysqli_query(...```

Comment: also read the documentation about parameter binding. You should prepare a statement using the value in $user instead of concatenating it in the string

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! Okay I will do, I'm still learning put I'll put it on my list of things to work through!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, your clock.php script needs to query the database for the latest entry for the currently logged in user and see if the last entry was a clockAction of "In" or "Out". I would write a query as:

`SELECT clockAction FROM clock WHERE user = '.$user.' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1`
Since you only need to know if the latest entry by the user was an "In" or an "Out" the query only needs to return the clockAction column, and by using ORDER BY time DESC, you would get a descending list of entries with the latest entry on top, and the LIMIT 1 just returns that latest entry, if "time" is in chronological order. Your php script can then assign the query result to a variable such as $lastClockAction, and that variable can be used to render one button or the other like this:
`if ($lastClockAction == 'In') //code to render "Clock Out" button
else // code to render "Clock In" button`
This will work even if the logged in user doesn't have any entries, because then your script should only render the "Clock In" button to the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how would I assign the query result like you suggested? Thank you

Comment: That would depend on how you are accessing your database in PHP, are you using the old mysql_query, or are you using PDO?